# how to decrease the size of ScrollBars on FireMonkey

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I have a ScrollBox in my application, I want to decrease the width of it's ScrollBars

how can I change the size of ScrollBars ?

I'm using Delphi XE6

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow.  Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for guidance on asking a good question.  To start with, please post a Minimal, Verifiable, and Complete example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and explain what's not working the way you'd expect.

Comment: Thanks, I will keep these in mind

Comment: Which kind of application you created: Firemonkey Mobile or Firemonkey Desktop Application?

Comment: @FilipeMartins FireMonkey Desktop Application

Comment: Try this one: Right-Click on your ScrollBox > Edit Custom Style. At Structure seach for ScrollBox1Style1 (you can rename later). Has a child with style name: `hscrollbar` and other `vscrollbar` that represents the scrollbars. Change the height property of the `hscrollbar` and the width of `vscrollbar`. Then click 'Apply and Close' at the menu bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one: Right-Click on your ScrollBox > Edit Custom Style. At Structure seach for `ScrollBox1Style1` (you can rename later). Has a child with style name: `hscrollbar` and other `vscrollbar` that represents the scrollbars. Change the height property of the `hscrollbar` and the width of `vscrollbar`. Then click 'Apply and Close' at the menu bar.

Comment: Thanks, How to hide the background of ScrollBar ? just show the vertical track, I have changed visible property of some styles but i don't know what style I should make invisible, when I invisible background or vscrollbar style scrollbar get invisible completely but I want to show only the vertical trackbar

Comment: Maybe you will need to create a new stylelookup for `htrack` and `vtrack` of `ScrollBox1hscrollbar1` and `ScrollBox1vscrollbar1` without the background.